# change the frequecy of a users voice, android

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do, is create an app that takes a recording of a persons voice, for example you could say " hello my name is James", the app would first record this, then change its frequency and give you an output.

The output would obviously sound stupid and maybe funny, but that is what I'm trying to do.

I have got the code to record and play anything that a user says, but how do I manipulate it, how do I change the pitch of the voice.

Comment: Hai , now I am facing same problem and did not get any library or even any way to do it.Have you done it

Answer (score 3):

I googled for the same requirement and got something like,soundpool can be used to achieve this. I tried to create it out of the stuff i got,but no success yet. but you can go through the links.These might help you.

http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

http://www.anddev.org/using_soundpool_instead_of_mediaplayer-t3115.html

http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=207

Comment: sorry, I didn't. it was quite long ago i replied. I am working in different field currently.

Comment: wow...it works like a charm... Im able to change voice to robot,cat etc using the links that you have provided..Thankyou so much